# How to cache all data with squid (Facebook, videos, downloads and .exe) on QNAP

Tags: cache, squid

Can anyone help me to cache Facebook, all videos, downloads, pictures and webpages in my squid server on my QNAP?

Below is my config. I want to use 4 GB for the cache.

I have tried everything and it is not working right.

```
# The user name and group name Squid will operate as
cache_effective_user httpdusr
cache_effective_group everyone

#
# Recommended minimum configuration:
#
# Auth Method
#auth_param basic program /share/MD0_DATA/.qpkg/Squid/opt/libexec/squid/ncsa_auth /etc/shadow
#auth_param basic children 5
#auth_param basic realm Squid proxy-caching web server
#auth_param basic credentialsttl 2 hours

acl manager proto cache_object
acl localhost src 127.0.0.1/32 ::1
acl to_localhost dst 127.0.0.0/8 0.0.0.0/32 ::1

# Example rule allowing access from your local networks.
# Adapt to list your (internal) IP networks from where browsing
# should be allowed
acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8 # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 172.16.0.0/12  # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/16 # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src fc00::/7 # RFC 4193 local private network range
acl localnet src fe80::/10 # RFC 4291 link-local (directly plugged) machines

acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80   # http
acl Safe_ports port 21   # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443  # https
acl Safe_ports port 70   # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210  # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280  # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488  # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591  # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777  # multiling http
acl CONNECT method CONNECT

#acl ncsa_users proxy_auth REQUIRED

#
# Recommended minimum Access Permission configuration:
#
# Only allow cachemgr access from localhost
http_access allow manager localhost
http_access deny manager

# Deny requests to certain unsafe ports
http_access deny !Safe_ports

# Deny CONNECT to other than secure SSL ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports

# We strongly recommend the following be uncommented to protect innocent
# web applications running on the proxy server who think the only
# one who can access services on "localhost" is a local user
#http_access deny to_localhost

#
# INSERT YOUR OWN RULE(S) HERE TO ALLOW ACCESS FROM YOUR CLIENTS
#

# Example rule allowing access from your local networks.
# Adapt localnet in the ACL section to list your (internal) IP networks
# from where browsing should be allowed
http_access allow localnet
#http_access allow ncsa_users

# And finally deny all other access to this proxy
http_access deny all

# Squid normally listens to port 3128
http_port 3128

# We recommend you to use at least the following line.
hierarchy_stoplist cgi-bin ?

# Uncomment and adjust the following to add a disk cache directory.
#cache_dir ufs /share/MD0_DATA/.qpkg/Squid/opt/var/squid/cache 100 16 256

cache_mem 8 MB
minimum_object_size 0 bytes
maximum_object_size 200 MB
maximum_object_size_in_memory 512 KB

# Leave coredumps in the first cache dir
coredump_dir /share/MD0_DATA/.qpkg/Squid/opt/var/squid/

access_log /share/MD0_DATA/.qpkg/Squid/opt/var/squid/logs/access.log squid
cache_log /share/MD0_DATA/.qpkg/Squid/opt/var/squid/logs/cache.log
cache_store_log /share/MD0_DATA/.qpkg/Squid/opt/var/squid/logs/store.log

# Add logfile rotated mechanism
logfile_rotate 7
debug_options rotate=1

#
mime_table /share/MD0_DATA/.qpkg/Squid/opt/etc/squid/mime.conf
pid_filename /share/MD0_DATA/.qpkg/Squid/opt/var/squid/run/squid.pid
diskd_program /share/MD0_DATA/.qpkg/Squid/opt/libexec/squid/diskd
unlinkd_program /share/MD0_DATA/.qpkg/Squid/opt/libexec/squid/unlinkd
icon_directory /share/MD0_DATA/.qpkg/Squid/opt/share/squid/icons
err_page_stylesheet /share/MD0_DATA/.qpkg/Squid/opt/etc/squid/errorpage.css
error_default_language en-us
error_directory /share/MD0_DATA/.qpkg/Squid/opt/share/squid/errors/en-us

# Add any of your own refresh_pattern entries above these.

# VIDEO CACHE
refresh_pattern ^http://(.*?)/get_video\? 10080 90% 432000 override-expire ignore-no-cache ignore-private
refresh_pattern ^http://(.*?)/videoplayback\? 10080 90% 432000 override-expire ignore-no-cache ignore-private
refresh_pattern -i (get_video\?|videoplayback\?id|videoplayback.*id) 161280 50000% 525948 override-expire ignore-reload

# facebook
refresh_pattern ((facebook.com)|(85.131.151.39)).*\.(jpg|png|gif) 129600 999999% 129600 ignore-reload override-expire ignore-no-cache ignore-no-store store-stale
refresh_pattern ((tagged.com)|(96.17.109.27)).*\.(jpg|png|gif) 129600 999999% 129600 ignore-reload override-expire ignore-no-cache ignore-no-store store-stale
refresh_pattern static\.ak\.fbcdn\.net*\.(jpg|gif|png) 129600 999999% 129600 ignore-reload override-expire ignore-no-cache ignore-no-store store-stale
refresh_pattern ^http:\/\/profile\.ak\.fbcdn.net*\.(jpg|gif|png) 129600 999999% 129600 ignore-reload override-expire ignore-no-cache ignore-no-store store-stale
refresh_pattern edgecastcdn.\net.*\.swf? 129600 999999% 129600 override-expire ignore-reload store-stale
refresh_pattern \.(jp(e?g|e|2)|tiff?|bmp|gif|png)($|&) 129600 999999% 129600 ignore-no-cache ignore-no-store reload-into-ims override-expire store-stale
refresh_pattern .zynga.net.*\.(jpg|gif|png|swf|mp3)($|&) 129600 999999% 129600 store-stale
refresh_pattern .zynga.com.*\.(jpg|gif|png|swf|mp3)($|&) 129600 999999% 129600 store-stale
refresh_pattern .farmville.net.*\.(jpg|gif|png|swf|mp3)($|&) 129600 999999% 129600 store-stale
refresh_pattern .farmville.com.*\.(jpg|gif|png|swf|mp3)($|&) 129600 999999% 129600 store-stale
refresh_pattern .ninjasaga.com.*\.(jpg|gif|png|swf|mp3)($|&) 129600 999999% 129600 store-stale
refresh_pattern .apps.facebook.com.*\.(jpg|gif|png|swf|mp3)($|&) 129600 999999% 129600 store-stale
refresh_pattern .frontierville.*\.(jpg|gif|png|swf|mp3)($|&) 129600 999999% 129600 store-stale
refresh_pattern .tagged.*\.(jpg|gif|png|swf|mp3)($|&) 129600 999999% 129600 store-stale

#ads
refresh_pattern ^.*(utm\.gif|ads\?|rmxads\.com|ad\.z5x\.net|bh\.contextweb\.com|bstats\.adbrite\.com|a1\.interclick\.com|ad\.trafficmp\.com|ads\.cubics\.com|ad\.xtendmedia\.com|\.googlesyndication\.com|advertising\.com|yieldmanager|game-advertising\.com|pixel\.quantserve\.com|adperium\.com|doubleclick\.net|adserving\.cpxinteractive\.com|syndication\.com|media.fastclick.net).* 129600 20% 129600 ignore-no-cache ignore-no-store ignore-private override-expire ignore-reload ignore-auth store-stale negative-ttl=40320 max-stale=1440
#specific sites
refresh_pattern ^.*safebrowsing.*google 129600 999999% 129600 override-expire ignore-reload ignore-no-cache ignore-no-store ignore-private ignore-auth negative-ttl=10080 store-stale
refresh_pattern (get_video\?|videoplayback\?|videodownload\?|\.flv?) 129600 99999999% 129600 override-expire ignore-reload store-stale
refresh_pattern \.(ico|video-stats) 129600 999999% 129600 override-expire ignore-reload ignore-no-cache ignore-no-store ignore-private ignore-auth override-lastmod negative-ttl=10080 store-stale

# pictures & images
refresh_pattern -i \.(gif|png|jpeg|jpg|bmp|tif|tiff|ico)$ 10080 50% 43200 override-expire override-lastmod reload-into-ims ignore-reload ignore-no-cache ignore-auth ignore-private store-stale
refresh_pattern -i \.(gif|png|jpeg|jpg|bmp|tif|tiff|ico)\? 10080 50% 43200 override-expire override-lastmod reload-into-ims ignore-reload ignore-no-cache ignore-auth ignore-private store-stale

# website
#refresh_pattern -i \.(xml|html|htm|js|jsp|txt|css|php|asp)$ 10080 50% 43200 override-expire override-lastmod reload-into-ims ignore-reload ignore-no-cache ignore-auth store-stale
refresh_pattern -i \.(xml|js|jsp|txt|css)$ 10080 50% 43200 override-expire override-lastmod reload-into-ims ignore-reload ignore-no-cache ignore-auth store-stale
refresh_pattern -i \.(xml|js|jsp|txt|css)\? 10080 50% 43200 override-expire override-lastmod reload-into-ims ignore-reload ignore-no-cache ignore-auth store-stale

#sound, video multimedia
refresh_pattern -i \.(flv|x-flv|mov|avi|qt|mpg|mpeg|swf|wmv)$ 10080 50% 43200 override-expire override-lastmod reload-into-ims ignore-reload ignore-no-cache store-stale
refresh_pattern -i \.(wav|mp3|mp4|au|mid)$ 10080 50% 43200 override-expire override-lastmod reload-into-ims ignore-reload ignore-no-cache ignore-auth ignore-private store-stale

# files
refresh_pattern -i \.(iso|deb|rpm|zip|tar|tgz|ram|rar|bin|ppt|doc)$ 10080 90% 43200 ignore-no-cache ignore-auth store-stale
refresh_pattern -i \.(zip|gz|arj|lha|lzh)$ 10080 100% 43200 override-expire ignore-no-cache ignore-auth store-stale
refresh_pattern -i \.(rar|tgz|tar|exe|bin)$ 10080 100% 43200 override-expire ignore-no-cache ignore-auth ignore-reload ignore-no-cache store-stale
refresh_pattern -i \.(hqx|pdf|rtf|doc|swf)$ 10080 100% 43200 override-expire ignore-no-cache ignore-auth store-stale
refresh_pattern -i \.(inc|cab|ad|txt|dll)$ 10080 100% 43200 override-expire ignore-no-cache ignore-auth store-stale

#IIX DOWNLOAD
refresh_pattern ^http:\/\/\.www[0-9][0-9]\.indowebster\.com\/(.*)(mp3|rar|zip|flv|wmv|3gp|mp(4|3)|exe|msi|zip) 43200 99999% 129600 reload-into-ims ignore-reload override-expire ignore-no-cache ignore-no-store store-stale ignore-auth

#default option
refresh_pattern ^ftp: 1440 20% 10080
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 1 0% 2
refresh_pattern ^gopher: 1440 0% 1440
refresh_pattern . 0 20% 4320 store-stale
```

Comment: What OS? Are your browsers using this proxy? How is your network setup? What is your IP range for your computers? Do you have enough free space to cache it? Do you realize 4GB is tiny? Do you have Squid setup to proxy items on port 443 (HTTPS)? Need more info

Answer (score 8):

**TRY THIS**

```
# Uncomment and adjust the following to add a disk cache directory.

#cache_dir ufs /share/MD0_DATA/.qpkg/Squid/opt/var/squid/cache 100 16 256

cache_mem 8 MB
minimum_object_size 0 bytes
maximum_object_size 200 MB
maximum_object_size_in_memory 512 KB
```

become

```
cache_dir ufs /share/MD0_DATA/.qpkg/Squid/opt/var/squid/cache 4000 16 256

cache_mem 8 MB
minimum_object_size 0 bytes
maximum_object_size 200 MB
maximum_object_size_in_memory 512 KB
```

hope it would help :)

Answer (score 3):

If you would like to cache content you may need to make caching rules under your squid open your squid configurations file and paste below rules for caching this will cached most of content you can separately for specific websites as well.

```
refresh_pattern ^ftp: 1440 20% 10080

refresh_pattern ^gopher: 1440 0% 1440

refresh_pattern -i \.(gif|png|jpg|jpeg|ico)$ 10080 90% 43200 override-expire ignore-no-cache ignore-no-store ignore-private

refresh_pattern -i \.(iso|avi|wav|mp3|mp4|mpeg|swf|flv|x-flv)$ 43200 90% 432000 override-expire ignore-no-cache ignore-no-store ignore-private

refresh_pattern -i \.(deb|rpm|exe|zip|tar|tgz|ram|rar|bin|ppt|doc|tiff)$ 10080 90% 43200 override-expire ignore-no-cache ignore-no-store ignore-private

refresh_pattern -i \.index.(html|htm)$ 0 40% 10080

refresh_pattern -i \.(html|htm|css|js)$ 1440 40% 40320

refresh_pattern . 0 40% 40320
# Specific rule for youtube caching.

refresh_pattern -i youtube.com/.* 10080 90% 43200
refresh_pattern (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0 0% 0
```

Sometimes, for no good reason, at least from our perspective, origin servers, such as youtube.com, do everything to make it difficult or impossible for you to cache content. The options above should help you to overcome some of these limitations.